# Define <Repositories> in my pom and download through my own Nexus Server

Tags: maven, nexus

I set up my own Nexus server and it works fine when I added setting.xml to my ~/.m2/. It can download artificats from the public repository through my Nexus server.

However, I need to depend on a project (sphinx4) which isn't in Central, but in nexus-oss repository. It isn't in my Nexus server. Based on the documentation, I added this to my POM:

```
 <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots-repo</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

And the dependency to my POM:

```
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>edu.cmu.sphinx</groupId>
          <artifactId>sphinx4-core</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.cmu.sphinx</groupId>
        <artifactId>sphinx4-data</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I am quite new to Nexus and Maven. My understanding is that since this library isn't in my Nexus server, so Maven will automatically download artifacts from the OSS repository due to the repository definition in my POM. However, it can't. This is the error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project wordex: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project com.bombw.core:wordex:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The 
following artifacts could not be resolved: edu.cmu.sphinx:sphinx4-
core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT, edu.cmu.sphinx:sphinx4-data:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could 
**not find artifact edu.cmu.sphinx:sphinx4-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in nexus 
(http://www.bombword.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]**
```

The highlighted error message seems to indicate that the build is looking for the artifact from my nexus server, but failed.

If I remove my customized setting.xml and not involve my own nexus server, my pom works fine. It can download the artifact from the repository definition.

My Nexus server should be configured right, since it can download all other needed artifacts from public repository and cache in my nexus server.

What might cause this? Can't figure it out.

Editted:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://www.bombword.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

Comment: Do you have an explanation why the error message mentions "http://www.bombword.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public"? Did you maybe set up a mirror-all directive in your settings.xml?

Comment: Configure the repository in Nexus and that's it.

Comment: if you use a nexus repository proxy you don't need to add repositories into  your pom. In fact I would recommend not to - repositories move around all the time... - you can add a proxy in nexus and point it to OSS Sonatype (if not already configured) and then add that repository to the public group in nexus. That should already work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach to your case is adding the new repository in Nexus itself and not to the pom. This is the great advantage of the Nexus repository manager.

You need to go to your Nexus as an admin and add the `sonatype` snapshots repository as a new proxied repository. See [documentation](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-new-repo.html).

Once added and indexed by Nexus, you should get the artifacts resolved by the maven build.

I hope this helps.